# Is there a Sanskrit (not Pali) version of the Five Precepts?

Tags: five-precepts, translation

Can anyone provide me a Sanskrit (not Pali) translation of the Five Precepts?

Comment: If you don't get an answer here, perhaps an alternative place to ask this question might be [the suttacentral.net forum](https://discourse.suttacentral.net/)?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the link that follows would be your one of your best options for tracking down a Sanskrit version of the Five Precepts. It indicated that this is to be found in the liturgy. Get in touch with them and see if they can provide more information.

http://nalandatranslation.org/offerings/notes-on-the-daily-chants/commentaries/ritual-for-taking-the-five-precepts/